# Java8 Stream api compare list

Tags: java

I have two sources for list of item details.

List 1 is -

```
List<ItemDetail> itemDetails;
```

Item details class has two attributes--

```
private String unit price; 
private String itemName;
```

List2- I got the other list from another source which has -

```
List<ItemDetail> itemDetails2;
```

My requirement is to compare the these two lists based on condition.

1- if the name is same -> check price-> if both are same then good

I have to compare all the elements -if all the items in list1 are present in list 2 and price& name are matching then I have send ok.

if for any items price is not matching i have to send - partial ok with a list of name which is MATCHED.

this one i tried-

```
List<ItemDetail> resultitemDetails = itemDetails.stream().filter(
        it->itemDetails.stream().anyMatch(
            i->i.getItemId().equals(it.getItemId())
        )
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Show some code. Can't really help without it.

Comment: It does not seem like a good idea to use Lists like this.  I would convert the two Lists to Map<String,String> with the key being item id and the value being price.

Comment: but it will extra space and tim complexity   to put in hash map

Comment: @Nitin it will always be slow to do something like .contains() on a List.  It would be much faster to perform that type of operation on a collection like a Set or Map.  You could implement equals and hashcode (and only use item id in them) in ItemDetail and use a Set instead of a List.  The Set and Map will take up more space, but each should operate much faster than the List.

Comment: The one you tried uses itemDetails twice, did you want to use itemDetails2? Also you need to explain why "the one you tried" doesn't work. Or include the "working" loop solution you have.

Answer (score 2):

It will not "add time and space complexity to put the items in a map". Space maybe - but only linear to the amount of items - but time complexity for map generation is O(n), map lookup O(1); the lookup you implement with iterating one list for each item of the other is O(n^2).

Do

```
// O(n) to generate map
Map<String, String> byName = 
    list.stream().collect(toMap(ItemDetails::getName, ItemDetails::getPrice));
// O(n) to filter second list (iterate n elements, O(1) lookup)
List<String> matchingNames = list2.stream().filter(
                                i -> byName.contains(i.getName()) &&
                                     byName.get(i.getName()).equals(i.getPrice())
                             .map(ItemDetails::getName);
                             .collect(toList());
boolean allValid = matchingNames.size() == list2.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a purely stream method that will will work but has extreme growth in increasing list size. O(n^2)

```
    List<ItemDetail> goodItems = itemDetails.stream().filter(
    it->itemDetails2.stream().anyMatch(
        i->i.getItemName().equals(it.getItemName()) && i.getUnitprice().equals(it.getUnitprice() )
    )).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<ItemDetail> partialMatchItem = itemDetails.stream().filter(
    it->itemDetails2.stream().anyMatch(
        i->i.getItemName().equals(it.getItemName()) && !i.getUnitprice().equals(it.getUnitprice() )
    )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The one below first inserts the items in a HashMap and then uses the fast lookup there instead of searching every item in the first list everytime:

```
    Map<String, String> listAsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    itemDetails.stream().forEach(entry -> listAsMap.put(entry.getItemName(), entry.getUnitprice()));

    List<ItemDetail> goodItemsHashMethod =  itemDetails2.stream().filter(
    i-> listAsMap.containsKey(i.getItemName()) 
    && listAsMap.get((i.getItemName())).equals(i.getUnitprice()) 
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: I didn't use `Collectors.toMap()` because it returns a `Map<Object, Object>` when used with a Stream. Don't know why.

Comment: Is this what you were trying to do with the Collectors.toMap()?

Map<String, String> listAsMap = itemDetails.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(ItemDetails::getItemName, ItemDetails::getUnitPrice));

Comment: yes exactly, I get `The method toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments (ItemDetail::getItemName, ItemDetail::getUnitPrice)` and `The type ItemDetail does not define getItemName(T) that is applicable here` when I try that even though my ItemDetail class returns a String on `getItemName()`

Comment: If you use the `.collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> entry.getValue()));` style then it gives the Map<Object, Object> as a return.